# Installing Nokogiri gem on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, nokogiri

I'm trying to install Ruby on my Windows environment. It works fine on my Ubuntu.

I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Ruby 2.0 seems to be correctly set, both DevKit and RubyInstaller.

But when I try to `bundle` ig Get the following:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.11'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby/RubyInstaller200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable.
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby/RubyInstaller200-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --with-iconv-dir
        --without-iconv-dir
        --with-iconv-include
        --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
        --with-iconv-lib
        --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
        --with-xml2-dir
        --without-xml2-dir
        --with-xml2-include
        --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
        --with-xml2-lib
        --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
        --with-xslt-dir
        --without-xslt-dir
        --with-xslt-include
        --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
        --with-xslt-lib
        --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
        --with-libxslt-config
        --without-libxslt-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libxml-2.0-config
        --without-libxml-2.0-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libiconv-config
        --without-libiconv-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/RubyInstaller200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.11 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby/RubyInstaller200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.11/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

I already have this gem installed, but in another version.

```
C:\wamp\www\holdsport>gem list | grep noko              
nokogiri (1.6.2.1 x64-mingw32)
```

It seems like libxml2 isn't installed but I couldn't find out how install it on windows.
I don't know if the message `extconf.rb failed` is because the libxml2 is missing or another issue.

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: You used the RubyInstaller for Windows (http://rubyinstaller.org/)?

Comment: Yes I did, https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Answer (score 4):

Nokogiri doesn't support x64 ruby 2.0, for whatever reason. Try installing the x86 version of ruby instead.

If `gem install nokogiri` *still* doesn't work, install the pre-release with `gem install nokogiri --pre`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the issue. Installing the --pre version won't help since it's a dependency from another gem. I'm a bit sceptic about using the x86 version because of one gem.

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me on Windows. I have ruby 2.1.5 with DevKit but cannot get the normal install to work. Thanks.